# Can assign value to input element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with a platform called Mendix. I built a simple app that takes the string from an input field and displays the wikipedia summary related to it.
The value in input field is considered if I type manually or paste in the input field. But when I set the value using inputElement.value = "some value" an empty string is considered by the app. Interestingly if I press a key after setting the value using javascript in the field, the string value is considered by the app. What is happening here. I tried to trigger the "keydown" event manually too but with no success. How should I go about this. Tried this code.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].focus()
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value = "This value must be read by the app"
var e = new Event("keydown");
  e.key="a";
  e.keyCode=e.key.charCodeAt(0);
  e.which=e.keyCode;
  e.altKey=false;
  e.ctrlKey=true;
  e.shiftKey=false;
  e.metaKey=false;
  e.bubbles=false;
  document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].dispatchEvent(e);
  document.getElementsByClassName('callToAction')[0].click()
```

Comment: Can you expose the piece of code please?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan exposed the code

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/exaL47u3/.

I took the html to be

```
<input type="text" class="a"/>
<input type="text" class="a"/>
<input type="text" class="a"/>
```

The js similar to yours

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0].focus()
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0].value = "Test value"
```

This is exactly as you do in your code. This seems to be totally fine. So, this part of your code is not at all buggy. Check to see where you are calling these codes.